# Generate unique Device Id using php

Tags: php, laravel

Hello friends i want to generate device Id using PHP ( FINTECH_XXXX.10/11/2020.1000001)
For each device 1000001 increases by +1 and date changes on daily basis.

Please help!!

Comment: use normal loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
$deviceIds = [];
$initNumber = 1000001;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $deviceId = "FINTECH_XXXX.$date.$initNumber";
    array_push($deviceIds, $deviceId);
    $initNumber++;
}
print("<pre>");
print_r($deviceIds);
```

this will output

```json
[
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000001",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000002",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000003",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000004",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000005",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000006",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000007",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000008",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000009",
"FINTECH_XXXX.19/11/2020.1000010"
]
```

Comment: I'M NOTGETTING ANY OUTPUT @kamlesh

Comment: `$deviceIds` not getting any id ?

Comment: Please help @kamlesh

Comment: you can try here as well https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler